# What is dot spec `.spec.ts` and why do typescript tests use them?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I haven't seen an example where a typescript project *doesn't* use .spec.ts for their tests.

So why even both putting `.spec.ts`? What is the purpose of `.spec.ts`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their purpose is to identify test files in Angular applications (among other frameworks). This it not a standard, just a naming convention which allows test files to be in the same folder as the corresponding file to be tested.

Comment: Oh? What's the standard naming convention?

Comment: Well there is none. Angular chose `.spec`, the Node.js backend framework NestJS allows `.spec` or `.test`. Other frameworks might chose one of these, or others...